# How to store multiple circles in a single PostGIS geometry column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I need to store multiple circles in a single geometry column in PostGIS.
So far I can store only one like this:

```
UPDATE element SET geo = ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(-71.1043443253471, 42.3150676015829), 6, 'quad_segs=8')  WHERE id = 1;
```

Is there a way to use GEOMETRYCOLLECTION here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: answered [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225932/how-to-convert-a-polygon-to-a-geometrycollection-type-in-postgis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate your buffers using `ST_Union` and then create the collection with `ST_ForceCollection`, e.g. to append a buffer to an existing geometry:

```
UPDATE element 
SET geo =   
  ST_ForceCollection(
    ST_Union(geo, ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(-80.10, 45.31), 3) ))
WHERE id = 1;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=32a3a71754f76d7999bbdc4b2c8ddb3f)

```
SELECT 
  ST_ForceCollection(
    ST_Union(
      ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(-71.10, 42.31), 6),
      ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(-80.10, 45.31), 3) 
  ));

                                                   st_astext                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POLYGON((-77.1576441587903 44.72472903395162,-77.32836140246613 44.161949702904735,-77.60559116309236 43.6432893009412,-77.97867965644035 43.188679656440364,-78.43328930094118 42.81559116309237,-78.95194970290473 42.538361402466144,-79.51472903395161 42.36764415879031,-80.1 42.31,-80.68527096604838 42.36764415879031,-81.24805029709526 42.53836140246614,-81.76671069905879 42.815591163092364,-82.22132034355963 43.18867965644036,-82.59440883690763 43.64328930094119,-82.87163859753385 44.16194970290473,-83.04235584120968 44.72472903395161,-83.1 45.309999999999995,-83.04235584120968 45.89527096604838,-82.87163859753386 46.45805029709526,-82.59440883690763 46.9767106990588,-82.22132034355964 47.431320343559634,-81.7667106990588 47.80440883690763,-81.24805029709528 48.08163859753386,-80.68527096604839 48.25235584120969,-80.10000000000001 48.31,-79.51472903395162 48.2523558412097,-78.95194970290474 48.08163859753387,-78.4332893009412 47.80440883690765,-77.97867965644036 47.431320343559655,-77.60559116309237 46.97671069905883,-77.32836140246614 46.45805029709529,-77.1576441587903 45.89527096604841,-77.1 45.31,-77.1576441587903 44.72472903395162)),POLYGON((-65.21528831758062 41.139458067903234,-65.55672280493228 40.01389940580947,-66.11118232618472 38.976578601882395,-66.8573593128807 38.06735931288072,-67.76657860188237 37.32118232618473,-68.80389940580945 36.766722804932286,-69.92945806790321 36.42528831758062,-71.09999999999998 36.31,-72.27054193209675 36.425288317580616,-73.39610059419053 36.76672280493228,-74.4334213981176 37.321182326184726,-75.34264068711927 38.06735931288071,-76.08881767381526 38.97657860188238,-76.64327719506771 40.01389940580945,-76.98471168241937 41.13945806790321,-77.1 42.30999999999998,-76.98471168241937 43.48054193209675,-76.64327719506772 44.60610059419052,-76.08881767381529 45.643421398117596,-75.3426406871193 46.55264068711927,-74.43342139811763 47.29881767381526,-73.39610059419056 47.85327719506771,-72.27054193209679 48.19471168241938,-71.10000000000002 48.31,-69.92945806790325 48.19471168241939,-68.80389940580949 47.85327719506773,-67.76657860188242 47.29881767381529,-66.85735931288073 46.55264068711931,-66.11118232618475 45.643421398117646,-65.55672280493229 44.60610059419057,-65.21528831758062 43.48054193209681,-65.1 42.31,-65.21528831758062 41.139458067903234)))
(1 row)
```

Or using a CTE

```
WITH j (geom) AS (
  VALUES (ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(-71.10, 42.31), 6)),
         (ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(-80.10, 45.31), 3))  
)
SELECT ST_ForceCollection(ST_Union(geom)) FROM j;

                                                   st_astext                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POLYGON((-77.1576441587903 44.72472903395162,-77.32836140246613 44.161949702904735,-77.60559116309236 43.6432893009412,-77.97867965644035 43.188679656440364,-78.43328930094118 42.81559116309237,-78.95194970290473 42.538361402466144,-79.51472903395161 42.36764415879031,-80.1 42.31,-80.68527096604838 42.36764415879031,-81.24805029709526 42.53836140246614,-81.76671069905879 42.815591163092364,-82.22132034355963 43.18867965644036,-82.59440883690763 43.64328930094119,-82.87163859753385 44.16194970290473,-83.04235584120968 44.72472903395161,-83.1 45.309999999999995,-83.04235584120968 45.89527096604838,-82.87163859753386 46.45805029709526,-82.59440883690763 46.9767106990588,-82.22132034355964 47.431320343559634,-81.7667106990588 47.80440883690763,-81.24805029709528 48.08163859753386,-80.68527096604839 48.25235584120969,-80.10000000000001 48.31,-79.51472903395162 48.2523558412097,-78.95194970290474 48.08163859753387,-78.4332893009412 47.80440883690765,-77.97867965644036 47.431320343559655,-77.60559116309237 46.97671069905883,-77.32836140246614 46.45805029709529,-77.1576441587903 45.89527096604841,-77.1 45.31,-77.1576441587903 44.72472903395162)),POLYGON((-65.21528831758062 41.139458067903234,-65.55672280493228 40.01389940580947,-66.11118232618472 38.976578601882395,-66.8573593128807 38.06735931288072,-67.76657860188237 37.32118232618473,-68.80389940580945 36.766722804932286,-69.92945806790321 36.42528831758062,-71.09999999999998 36.31,-72.27054193209675 36.425288317580616,-73.39610059419053 36.76672280493228,-74.4334213981176 37.321182326184726,-75.34264068711927 38.06735931288071,-76.08881767381526 38.97657860188238,-76.64327719506771 40.01389940580945,-76.98471168241937 41.13945806790321,-77.1 42.30999999999998,-76.98471168241937 43.48054193209675,-76.64327719506772 44.60610059419052,-76.08881767381529 45.643421398117596,-75.3426406871193 46.55264068711927,-74.43342139811763 47.29881767381526,-73.39610059419056 47.85327719506771,-72.27054193209679 48.19471168241938,-71.10000000000002 48.31,-69.92945806790325 48.19471168241939,-68.80389940580949 47.85327719506773,-67.76657860188242 47.29881767381529,-66.85735931288073 46.55264068711931,-66.11118232618475 45.643421398117646,-65.55672280493229 44.60610059419057,-65.21528831758062 43.48054193209681,-65.1 42.31,-65.21528831758062 41.139458067903234)))
(1 row)
```